# Confuse "==null" and "==" "" in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, null, is-empty

I have a simple issue related `==null` and `==""` ,i think everybody know this issue .

Here's an example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void reorderingCriteia() {
    ListModelList<ReorderData> headerList = new ListModelList<ReorderData>();
    List<String> headerId = new ArrayList<String>();
    String userReorderSelection = Services.userPreferenceService().getUserPreference().getUserOption("PROCESS_CHECKLIST_COLUMN_REORDER");

    if (userReorderSelection == null || userReorderSelection == "") {
        int i = 0;
        for (ReorderData rd : availableReorderList) {
            headerList.add(rd);
            headerId.add("" + i);
            i++;
        }

        folderProcessModel.setHeaderList(headerList);
        folderProcessModel.setHeaderId(headerId);

    } else {
        headerList = ReorderDialogViewModelNew.jsonStringToList("FOLDER_PERMIT_LIST_COLUMN_REORDER", userReorderSelection, false);
        headerId = compHelper.intializeSequnce(headerList, folderProcessModel.getAvailableHeaders());
        folderProcessModel.setHeaderList(headerList);
        folderProcessModel.setHeaderId(headerId);

    }
}
```

I have some questions:

1. Here this code use `if (userReorderSelection == null || userReorderSelection == "")`. Can i use this condition `if (userReorderSelection == null)` ?
2. What is the difference between two ?

Comment: In addition to what the answers are saying, evaluating Strings with `==` (besides null) is considered bad form in Java; however, due to String interning (whereby literals like `"is a literal"` and `""` are cached), sometimes the `==` check can somewhat deceptively return the "correct" result. `"literal".equals(reference)` is also a "safer" check because it will not throw a NPE if the ref is null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`== null` checks for `null` reference.

`== ""` check for blank/empty string reference. Here you could use `str.equals("")` to check if the string is empty/blank or not. `==` is used for object reference checks. Or you can use the `String.isEmpty()` to check the same.

Also, if you use just `if (userReorderSelection == null)`, then you'll only be checking if the `userReorderSelection` is `null` or not and it won't determine whether the String is empty or not.

Answer (score 5):

As everyone replied:

- "" checks for empty String.
- null checks for null reference.

Use [**StringUtils** from apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) to eliminate  two conditions. **StringUtils.isEmpty(yourVariable)** this condition will handle both cases.

Answer (score 2):

`""` --> indicates empty String in Java. Rather than using `userReorderSelection == ""` it is preferable to us

```
userReorderSelection.isEmpty() // But make sure that userReorderSelection is not null
```

`null` --> indicates Null references (can be reference of any object)

If you do not have this check it may result in NullPointerException if you try to use this reference. Empty String will not throw such exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

`== null` checks to see if the object reference is null.
`== ""` checks to see if the object reference equals a blank string

str.equals ("") checks to see if your String object contains the empty string.

I guess what you want is

```
if (userReorderSelection == null || userReorderSelection.equals (""))
```